# illustrator printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, digital-printing

i clip an image in 8.5 "x11" standard paper size. and want to write on it. do i have to place any other rectangle behind it? so that the printing guy wont have ny problem to print it? or writing on the clipping masked image will be enough! i just need to know....[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked.

Comment: well you know if i dnt put any thing above artboard... the printing guy/company will use their own paper right/ (i learn it from here) so i want to know  f i write on the image will that cause any problem?? i mean will the printing guy print it at their own sweet will?using their own paper as i didn't put anything above the art board except the clipped image)

Comment: or the clipping masked  image is enough to act as the background paper?

Comment: I still don't understand. The **artboard** in Illustrator designates the printable area. Whatever is on the artboard will be printed.

Comment: so writing on the clipping mask image will be all? it will be printed as is was put on the artboard?-- right? the image and the writing--- it will be the end result?

Comment: In general... what you **see** will be printed if it is on the artboard.

Comment: Thank you... i get the picture.

Comment: i dnt know whether you gonna answer it not.. but am asking anyway. please be patient and answer scott. PLEASE. i cant live with confusion. am giving two scenarios.

Comment: 1. i draw three red dots on the artboard. And nothing behind it(no white color rectangle the same as the art board size, i mean no background,only three dots on the artboard). I save the ai file and take to the printer guy. Tell him i want it to be printed on black paper. He put white paper on the machine and the printer will apply black color on the white paper and the end result will be a black paper having three red dots on it. YES OR NO.

Comment: 2- i have three clipping mask image on artboard   in a scattered manner. But this time i place a white rectangle behind them same as the art board size. save the ai file take it to the printer guy. And want it to be printed in a blue paper.
So-
Will the printer print it as a white paper having three images on it? (as i dnt color the background  blue)
Or
The printer guy change the color of the white background and make it blue and then he/she wud print it?

Comment: Apologies, but your initial post is so confusingly written that it is incomprehensible. To get decent answers, the question has to be understandably written and clear. I *strongly* suggest you read [ask] and [answer], then [edit] your question to be clearer, or someone will vote to close it as unclear.

Comment: 1. Your question is invalid if you ask the printer to print on black paper you get a black result with darker spots on it. But if you send printer a black image with red dots then you bet a black background with red dots as its printed on white paper. 2. It is very rare for printers to have white ink, or in many cases even possibility to print it at all. So unless you have previously discussed this with your printer and agreed to print white odds are they will not print it. Even when you ask for white they frequently screw things up and dont print it.

Comment: am sorry if my question is not clear. to put in words all these technical matters is sometimes painful and difficult.  it got 2 closing votes already.... :(  @GerardFalla

Comment: @joojaa Thank you. your comment helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** Do not rely on masks, rectangles or any other graphic elements to indicate print area. To prevent erros, select the appropriate page size in document settings.

I used to be the printer guy and received all kind of files and formats to print. 
The best advice about error free printing is "information, information, information". 
You have to tell every detail about what you want. If the art is sent by a website form, use the comments field. If it is sent by email, write the instructions instead of just attaching the file.
Write instructions on the file name, like "poster - 8.5x11 no resize - CMYK - Portrait.PDF".
Select the appropriate/correspondent page size in the document. 
Do not rely on masks, background rectangles or random lines to indicate the print area, it is confusing. 
If it is extremely necessary, write instructions on the final art itself, OUTSIDE the print area and if you have any other questions, ask the printer guy if more information is needed.

Comment: Thankyou so much. can you please tell me what makes an illustrator file broken?

Comment: i mean when printing company term an ai file 'broken' ....and they cant open it?

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin you should as a general rule not send AI files. send PDF files. If you send ai files be sure to send any linked assets also.

Comment: Well a lot of things can damage AI files. Generally speaking a file goes wrong when Illustrator try to decode it and find something in the code it cannot deal neither ignore. It can be inexistent font (in this case AI asks for new font and goes on), complex vectors multiplied inside patterns or file data corruption. 

Recovering is unlikely, but it's possible try other programs  (like Corel Draw or Inkscape) to open the file and convert it, so work could be restored some way.

Comment: oh yes. sorry. i knew that. Thankyou @joojaa

Comment: @AleMacedo wow. Thank you. learnt lots from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, white (especially in a background) is read by printers as "no ink" and so what you leave white on a design will end up the colour of the paper, as it gets "knocked out" in the printing process.

If you stop and think about it, this makes sense: if you were printing on white paper, anything white in a design would be created in the print via not inking that area - so by extension, if your chosen bond is a mid-brown craft paper, the white design areas will end up craft paper brown in your final product.

As to creating false coloured paper by laying down that colour or tone in a background shape - this will work only if you are then having the paper trimmed to remove the portion left un-inked by the press or printer - despite all advertising indicating otherwise, there is still no printer which truly prints edge-to-edge, so anything requiring colour to the very edge is created by setting what's called int he industry a "bleed" - that is, a distance BEYOND the edge of the artboard and beyond the printing area to which you extend all colour fields or images intended to be at the very edge of the paper.

The printer then trims down to the new edge, and your colour field or image now goes right to the edge - or "bleeds".

This of course requires the raw print to be done on a larger sheetstock and trimmed to the appropriate size, so you then pay for the labour to trim and the original paperstock size used to create the final product.

> It is true there *are* specific special conditions in which white may
>   actually be a colour of ink or toner explicitly called for - but this
>   is an atypical workflow relative to the vast preponderance of prints -
>   and bluntly - spot colours, separations, Pantone definitions and so on
>   are the province of the industry of professional graphic designers and
>   print shops - of which you clearly are not part.

I hope this helps clarify things a bit - I am really unsure that I'm answering the question you intend, as it's very unclear - but based on the comments thread you have with Scott, I *think* this might help.

Comment: Thank you so much. i have learnt a LOT from your answer. Thank you again... i simply wanted to know -- if i have a clipping mask image in a standard paper size (8.5"x11") and write on it - will that cause any problem for the printer-- YES OR NO. simple. but yeah your answer helps me to clear my concept :)